# A question on init and activation hooks

Tags: plugin-development

I have a question on the following code at https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/#example

```
function pluginprefix_setup_post_type() {
    // register the "book" custom post type
    register_post_type( 'book', ['public' => true] );
}
add_action( 'init', 'pluginprefix_setup_post_type' );

function pluginprefix_install() {
    // trigger our function that registers the custom post type
    pluginprefix_setup_post_type();

    // clear the permalinks after the post type has been registered
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pluginprefix_install' );
```

Why does `pluginprefix_setup_post_type` need to be called on both `init` and `activation`? I tried an example plugin, commenting out the call to `pluginprefix_setup_post_type` in `pluginprefix_install` and adding the `label` like the following.

```
function pluginprefix_setup_post_type() {
    // register the "book" custom post type
    register_post_type( 'book', ['public' => true, 'label' => 'Books'] );
}
add_action( 'init', 'pluginprefix_setup_post_type' );

function pluginprefix_install() {
    // trigger our function that registers the custom post type
    // pluginprefix_setup_post_type();

    // clear the permalinks after the post type has been registered
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pluginprefix_install' );
```

And the code works fine too. I can see the `Books` in the Admin menu once I activate the plugin.

So what is the benefit of calling it twice?

Comment: When you say works fine you mean the permalink cache is set up correctly for the new type? I guess it's just being extra careful then in case the plugin activation code is called without the plugin being loaded in the original page load, because then it would miss the init hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mistaken and the activation didn't work correctly: you won't have the new post type set up in the permalinks cache.

Here's [activate_plugin() in 5.4](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L626). You can see the sequence is

- wp-admin/plugins.php loads without the new plugin; init is triggered now
- activate_plugin() PHP-includes the new plugin, loading it and registering its hooks; it's now too late for the plugin's init hook to be called
- activate_plugin() calls the global activate_plugin hook
- activate_plugin() calls the plugin-specific activate hook

So if you're relying on the init hook to register your post type in the activation case it won't have been called before `flush_rewrite_rules()`. Not that you'll see any errors here, but the new post type won't be set up in the permalink cache.

(That all is unless, on the very off chance you have an activate_plugin hook that triggers init, but that seems unlikely and definitely isn't the default.)

Comment: Hmm. Is there no way that one call is enough? It must be called twice?

Comment: It's not called twice: when you're activating the plugin the register_activation_hook handler is called; once the plugin is activated, the init version will be called. They're never both called on the same page load.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. Init is called for every request but activation is not. For activation hook, if I do not register the new post type, I don't even need to call flush_rewrite_rules(). Also we don't want to flush_rewrite_rules in init for every request.

Comment: Yes, that's right: init is called on every page load after the plugin has been activated; the activation hook is only called once but this plugin's init won't have been called that time. Yes, the flush_rewrite_rules call is only needed if you're adding or removing a custom post type from the site (or something else that would affect routing) and it's meant to be called once as a setup step and then all future page loads will use cached routing rules.